# jQuery Featherlight with content from api, loads on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, featherlight.js

Im calling a function to write content from a json string in a lightbox. I have my function working and populating the lightbox when I use the following

```
<a data-featherlight="<div id='dataplan_list_container'><table id='dataplan_list'></table></div>" onclick="dataPlanOutput('FR');" data-target="data_plan">France</a>
```

However I dont want every link to contain

```
data-featherlight="<div id='dataplan_list_container'><table id='dataplan_list'></table></div>"
```

I tried creating a target div on the page with

```
<a data-featherlight="#dataplan_list_container" onclick="dataPlanOutput('FR');" data-target="data_plan">France</a>
<div id='dataplan_list_container'><table id='dataplan_list'></table></div>
```

But when I use this the first time I click on the link the lightbox loads empty.

Can I set the template in javascript and call it dynamically on click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use the ligthbox on [`$(document).ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) so all DOM content is loaded? If not, then consider using it.

Also you can [manually bind](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#bind-featherlight) all links to the needed content:

```js
function dataPlanOutput(loc) {}

$('a.fl').featherlight({
    targetAttr: 'href'
});
```

```css
body>#dataplan_list_container {
  display:none
}
#dataplan_list_container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
#dataplan_list {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 90px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #606dbc, #606dbc 10px, #465298 10px, #465298 20px);
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/1.6.1/release/featherlight.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/1.6.1/release/featherlight.min.css" />


<a class="fl" href="#dataplan_list_container" onclick="dataPlanOutput('FR');" data-target="data_plan">France</a><br>
<a class="fl" href="#dataplan_list_container" onclick="dataPlanOutput('RU');" data-target="data_plan">Russia</a><br>
<div id='dataplan_list_container'><table id='dataplan_list'></table></div>
```